# Exception with no thread name

Tags: java, multithreading

One of my multi-threaded applications does not include the thread name when it throws an exception. I get exceptions like below

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at dataimporter.Importer.run(Importer.java:201)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there anyway for it to include the thread name?

Comment: Statement in `Importer.java` class on line `201` tries to access the 1st element of an empty `ArrayList`.

Comment: @PM77-1 yes I know, but how can I include the thread name?

Comment: Have you already found [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/uncaught-java-thread-exceptions/240148320)?

Answer (score 4):

You can register an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` with your `Thread` and print out the information you need.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(..);
thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, ex) -> // fancy Java 8 syntax
    System.out.println(t.getName() + " " + ex)
); // or print the stack trace after it
thread.start();
```

The above has some Java 8 syntax. If you aren't using that, you can simply use an anonymous class.

```
UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println(t.getName() + " " + ex);             
    }
};
thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
```

Comment: +1, however, how do you know the OP is using Java 8?

Comment: @hexafraction I don't :(.